# Hadoop jar execution failing on class not found

Tags: java, class, unix, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running my hadoop job and it is failing on class not found. 4 java files in total.

```
logProcessor.java
logMapper.java
logReducer.java
logParser.java
```

Everything is in a com folder on unix and I have "package com;" in the first line in all classes

that means if you do below command 
    head -5 *java
You will see
    package com; 
in all 4 files.

logProcessor is the Driver class. All files are in "com" folder on unix.

```
ls -ltr com/
logProcessor.java
logMapper.java
logReducer.java
logParser.java

I compiled the java program and made a jar out of it.

hadoop jar /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/xxxx/jarFiles/LogParser.jar com.LogProcessor /user/hdfs/flume/2015-03-30/03 /user/xxxx/output_xxx
```

It gives me below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.RFCLogProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:201)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that I was doing was right. Except that the classes which got created didnt have execute permission on them

So I did

chmod -R 777 com/

and jar'd it again and ran it with same above command and it executed.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to write your jar path in classpath. write directory path of your jar file into .bashrc file.

Then you can using below command:

hadoop jar directorypath/yourjarname.jar packagename.mainclassname outputpath