# Error in executing jar file in hadoop multi node clustering

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to implement Eleuni_max application on hadoop multi node clustering . But I am getting error while running the command:

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar units.jar hadoop.ProcessUnits input1_dir output_dir

..here is the source code:

```
package hadoop; 

import java.util.*; 

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;



public class ProcessUnits 
{ 
   //Mapper class 
   public static class E_EMapper extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Mapper<LongWritable ,/*Input key Type */ 
   Text,                /*Input value Type*/ 
   Text,                /*Output key Type*/ 
   IntWritable>        /*Output value Type*/ 
   { 

  //Map function 
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
  OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,   
  Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
  { 
     String line = value.toString(); 
     String lasttoken = null; 
     StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t"); 
     String year = s.nextToken(); 

     while(s.hasMoreTokens())
        {
           lasttoken=s.nextToken();
        } 

     int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken); 
     output.collect(new Text(year), new IntWritable(avgprice)); 
  } 


} 


   //Reducer class 
   public static class E_EReduce extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > 
   {  


  //Reduce function 
  public void reduce( Text key, Iterator <IntWritable> values, 
     OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
     { 
        int maxavg=30; 
        int val=Integer.MIN_VALUE; 

        while (values.hasNext()) 
        { 
           if((val=values.next().get())>maxavg) 
           { 
              output.collect(key, new IntWritable(val)); 
           } 
        } 

     } 


}  


   //Main function 
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception 
   { 
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(ProcessUnits.class); 

  conf.setJobName("max_eletricityunits"); 
  conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 
  conf.setMapperClass(E_EMapper.class); 
  conf.setCombinerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
  conf.setReducerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
  conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class); 
  conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class); 

  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0])); 
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])); 



    JobClient.runJob(conf); 
   } 
} 
error :
hadoop@hadoop:~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar units.jar hadoop.ProcessUnits input1_dir output_dir 
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadoop.ProcessUnits
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

Comment: hadoop@hadoop:~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar units.jar hadoop.ProcessUnits input1_dir output_dir 
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadoop.ProcessUnits
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop jar execution failing on class not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438893/hadoop-jar-execution-failing-on-class-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your code and was able to start the processing,please check the way you are creating the jar. You might not be including your main class while compiling the jar.

Can you please try out the below things , I can run smoothly using your code:-

1. echo $JAVA_HOME.
2. export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
3. Create package 'hadoop'( mkdir hadoop). ( To maintain the package name structure for hadoop to understand ).
4. Copy 'ProcessUnits.java' inside hadoop folder.
5. hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main hadoop/ProcessUnits.java
6. jar -cf units.jar hadoop/ProcessUnits*.class
7. Your jar is created. You can run the below command :-
   hadoop jar units.jar hadoop/ProcessUnits inputDir outputDir

Comment: Creating jar for the program I used two command                                       $ javac -classpath hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar -d units ProcessUnits.java 
$ jar -cvf units.jar -c units/                                                                             I also check the command u said $hadoop jar error_got.jar hadoop.ProcessUnits filename01 output01  the I got #not a valid JAR: /home/hadoop/error_got

Comment: I have made the JAR folder in /home/hadoop so I gave the command $hadoop jar units.jar hadoop.ProcessUnits input11_dir output11_dir but again sown Not a valid JAR: /home/hadoop/units.jar

Comment: I made my jar name as "error got".
The command to make the jar :
1) cd <dir where code is kept>.
2) javac -classpath ${your_HADOOP_CLASSPATH} -d <destination_dir_to keep jar> <main_class_name.java>
3) jar -cvf <jar_name_to create>.jar -c <destination_dir_to keep jar> .
4) Now your location contains the jar.

Command to run :-
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar location /< name of the jar>.jar hadoop.ProcessUnits input1_dir output_dir

Comment: The Problem has not solved.I m writing all the command that I have used.    1. $cd /home/hadoop/ ( where I have save the ProcessUnits.java and sample.txt where sample.txt is the input file ) 2.$mkdir units ( create a units directory in /home/hadoop/).3.$javac -classpath /home/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar -d units ProcessUnits.java (/home/hadoop/ copied the hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar).4. $jar -cvf units.jar -c units/.5.$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input11_dir( create an input directory in hdfs).

Comment: 6.$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -put /home/hadoop/sample.txt input11_dir( sample.txt is input file copied to input11_dir ).7.$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -ls input11_dir ( verify input directory ). 8. $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar units.jar ProcessUnits input11_dir output11_dir

Comment: Can you paste what is the error you are getting ?
Can you please tell me the directory structure and the files inside it.
I hope you already have all the dependency jars of hadoop present.

Comment: hadoop@hadoop:-$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar /home/hadoop/units.jar jar hadoop.ProcessUnits input_dir output_dir                                 warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.                                                   Exception in thread  "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jar              at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)                  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)                 at java.security.AccessController.doprivileged(Native Method )

Comment: error:                                                                                                             at java.net.URLClassLoader.findclass(URLClassLoader.java:347)            at java.langClassLoader.loadclass(classLoader.java:425)                               at java.langClassLoader.loadclass(classLoader.java:358)                             at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)                                              at java.lang.Class.forName0(class.java:278)                                             at org,apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java.153)

Comment: Can you please try out the below things , I can run smoothly using your code:-
1) echo $JAVA_HOME.
2) export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
3) Create package 'hadoop'( mkdir hadoop).
4) Copy 'ProcessUnits.java' inside hadoop folder.
5) hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main hadoop/ProcessUnits.java
6) jar -cf units.jar hadoop/ProcessUnits*.class
7) Your jar is created. You can run the below command :-
hadoop jar <location of units.jar> hadoop/ProcessUnits <input>  <output>

Comment: @ Aysha :- I have edited the main answer which I primarily provided also. Do let me know in case you still face errors.

Comment: Actually I m new in hadoop so plz don't mind by my questions. can u tell me how to I know my hdfs path on hadoop and also if I make a directory in hdfs then how can I remove those directories from hdfs??

Comment: can u plz tell me how should I set ~/.bashrc file ?

Comment: No issues..To know hdfs path.. Run the command "hdfs dfs -ls /". To remove dir simply do "hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash <dir_name>". Its better to use eclipse or any IDE to compile your code. To edit ~/.bashrc, execute "vi ~/.bashrc".If your problem is solved,please accept my primary answer nd upvote it.

Comment: hadoop@hadoop:~/hadoop$ hadoop jar units.jar hadoop/ProcessUnits i_dir o_dir Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.17/03/05 10:57:20 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.17/03/05 10:57:21 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library 17/03/05 10:57:21 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded 17/03/05 10:57:21 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1 17/03/05 10:57:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job:job_201703051037_0001

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at hadoop.ProcessUnits$E_EMapper.map(ProcessUnits.java:39)
at hadoop.ProcessUnits$E_EMapper.map(ProcessUnits.java:17)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: hadoop@hadoop:~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -ls o_dir/
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
Found 1 items drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop supergroup  0 2017-03-05 10:57 /user/hadoop/o_dir/_logs

Comment: hadoop@hadoop:~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -cat o_dir/part-00000
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

cat: File does not exist: /user/hadoop/o_dir/part-00000

Comment: hadoop@hadoop:~/hadoop$ hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main hadoop/WordCount.javaWarning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
hadoop@hadoop:~/hadoop$ jar -cf units.jar hadoop/WordCount*.class
hadoop@hadoop:~/hadoop$ hadoop jar units.jar hadoop/WordCount input_dir output_dir Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
17/03/06 02:41:48 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.17/03/06 02:41:48 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or jobConf#setJar(String).

Comment: 17/03/06 02:41:49 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1 17/03/06 02:41:49 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library 17/03/06 02:41:49 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded17/03/06 02:41:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201703052335_0001
17/03/06 02:41:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/03/06 02:42:02 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201703052335_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadoop.WordCount$Map at      org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:857)at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:718)at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: 17/03/06 02:42:12 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection refused (Connection refused)
17/03/06 02:42:12 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputConnection refused (Connection refused)
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201703052335_0001
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=24389

Comment: 17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
17/03/06 02:42:19 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
17/03/06 02:42:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
17/03/06 02:42:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
17/03/06 02:42:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1

Comment: Please give a sample of the input file you are working on..
part files created from reducer will be part-r-<reducer number> like part-r-00000 , part-r-00001 ,so on.
In the place of input dir, give the absolute file name. To get all files in a dir for input, we need to add some lines of code in driver.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial and here is the sample.txt https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm                   I have set up hadoop-1.2.1 and I have not set up any yarn file . Is this is the reason of errors.. The most frequent error I m getting is mapred can not connect output I mean output Connection failed.

Comment: The old API is deprecated. Try to use the code with new API. You can use eclipse or any IDE for compiling the code,(manually is not encouraged).Try setting hadoop 2.0 in your cluster.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Comment: Deepan Ram I have successfully run wordcount code but I think this code hase some problem . I am getting this error Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!                                                  . at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:873)    at ProcessUnits.main(ProcessUnits.java:167)                                         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)        at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

Comment: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: This code is written in old API and expects dependency jars to be in some particular location.
In the new API, the dependency jars are placed in different location, so this error comes when old API code is run with new version of hadoop without setting some parameters.

Comment: Deepan Ram can u give me by modifying the code in new API .. I don't have knowledge about API .

Comment: Aysha : You can check the new version of Word Count over here :-  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Comment: Deepan Ram I have already followed that tutorial and successfully run that WordCount program . But I wanted rin this ProcessUnits Program .